# How to check an email address smtp host?

Tags: vb.net, smtpclient

Im trying to send an email using System.Net.Mail,the SmtpClient instance requires a host specified, the issue is, i need it to be able to send the email with any mail i pass in the credentials.
In most cases it will be just a matter of using "smtp."+"whatever is after the @",but in some cases like outlook using stmp.live, and business with mails like something@mybusiness.com that are in reality gmail that wouldnt be an option
Is there any way to get the smtp server using just the email address?

```
        SmtpServer = New SmtpClient()
    With SmtpServer
        .UseDefaultCredentials = False
        .Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("something@something.com", "somePassword")
        .Host = "smtp_from_that_random_email"
        .Port = 587
    End With
```

Comment: The SMTP server is the one that you use for sending email.  It's not, generally, the one you use for receiving email.  And when you are sending email, you typically always connect to the same SMTP server (the one related to the `From` address, not the one related to the `To` address).  If you connect to the receiver's SMTP server and try to send an email from a different address, most SMTP servers will reject the request.

Comment: That is the thing, the mail from where im sending the message its not static, sometimes i would send from a gmail account, sometimes from an outlook account, sometimes from an 1und1 account

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood which email address you were referring to. So, you are saying you want to automatically determine SMTP server via the `From` email address. That makes more sense. Well, my next question is, if you already need to store the email address and the password, why not just also store the host?  It's not like you'll be able to automatically detect the password from their address. I'm not trying to be difficult. It's an honest question. Perhaps you do have a good reason. But given the fact that the simple answer probably is "you can't auto-determine the host", it's worth asking.

Comment: Mostly cause the application will be used by random users, worst case scenario will be that, asking the user to give the smtp(since most users will have 0 idea wich one is i was trying to fill that using the email to determine the smtp)

Comment: Well, I could be wrong, but my assumption was, whenever any application does that (which is rare, but, for instance, some email clients will automatically setup the host for you just from a given email address), all it's doing is looking it up in a list of popular email providers, where if you enter one of the popular ones, it already knows the host so you don't have to enter it.  If you enter an email address from a lesser known host, they'll still ask you for the SMTP server address.  Perhaps there is some web API you can query for those popular ones, but if so, I don't know of it.

Comment: The app manages sales from a business,and sends the pdf bill to the client(will be used by more than 1 business, so the email(s) to use to send each bill is out of my control, and the app will be probably managed by users with knowledge basically limited to "what is an email")

Comment: The list idea sounds like the best solution, i will go with that (and if not in the list, welp, they will have to learn to google i guess) thank you for the help

Comment: The situation you have is similar to wanting to send a letter to John without knowing which country John is in. However, *someone* does know - you need them to supply that information. You could add a "Settings" form to your program for that to be entered. N.B. Many,  but not all, SMTP servers will need `.EnableSsl = True`.